# Regex match left side of comma-separated expression

Tags: regex

Desire to create a regex to match the left side of an expression that is comma-separated as follows, preferably ignoring any whitespace:

`abc = a1, def = b2, ghi = c3`

Expression would match `abc` `def` and `ghi`

Have used this regex so far `(?<=,).*?(?=\=)`, however it doesn't match the first value and does not ignore whitespace.

Comment: Perhaps `\b(\w+)(?=\s*=)`?

Comment: Or capture and match  `(\w+)\s+=\s+\w+(?=,|$)` https://regex101.com/r/G7s7Ir/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern does not match the first value because the positive lookbehind `(?<=,)` asserts a comma to the left which is not there for the first value in the example string.

The pattern does not ignore whitespace because in this part `.*?(?=\=)` the "dot star" can match (including spaces) to the point that the assertion `(?=\=)` is true.

One option to get the first value is to use a capture group and match the pattern that follows ending either on a comma or assert the end of the string.

```
(\w+)\s+=\s+\w+(?:,|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `(\w+)` Capture 1+ word characters in *group 1*
- `\s+=\s+` Match `=` between whitespace chars
- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `(?:,|$)` Match either a comma or assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iVsJ1N/1)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
\w+(?= =)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/41DONxcvcp2jJR).

In English, *words characters the are followed by `" ="`*.